# Show $\overline{\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz} =- \oint_{\gamma}\overline{f(z)}\cdot z^{-2}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $U \subset \Bbb C$ and $f:U \to \Bbb C$ continuous. Furthermore let $\gamma: [0,2 \pi] \to U$ be a curve given by $\gamma(t)=exp(it)$. To show is:
$$\overline{\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz} =- \oint_{\gamma}\overline{f(z)}\cdot z^{-2}dz$$
I could show:
$\overline{\int_\gamma \! f(z) \,dz}=\overline{\int_0^{2\pi} \! f(e^{it})\cdot ie^{it} \,dt}=\int_0^{2\pi} \! \overline{f(e^{it})\cdot ie^{it}} \,dt$ but now I can't end the proof. Can someone helps me?

Comment: You are almost there. Do the same for the other side and use $\overline{e^{it}}=e^{-it}$

Comment: Thank you! I don't saw this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$-\int_\gamma\overline{f(z)}z^{-2}dz=-\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(e^{it})}e^{-2it}ie^{it}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(e^{it})}(-i)e^{-it}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(e^{it})ie^{it}}dt=\cdots$$